# Function expects to return value in C

Tags: c, function, void

I'm a newbie at C, I am working on someone else's code and I am trying to get rid of a warning that looks like this:

```
warning: function expects to return value: myfunc
```

myfunc is declared like this, (I believe it defaults to int)

```
myfunc(int id, int age) {

   ...
   return;

}
```

So I try to put void behind myfunc so that it looks like this

```
void myfunc(int num, int age) {
```

I get an error:

> identifier redeclared: myfunc
>
> ```
>     current : function() returning void
>
>     previous: function() returning int : "students.c", line 233
> ```

But when I go to line 233 of students.c, this is just the first place that I actually call the function. Why is this happening?

I know I could change `return` to `return 0;` and then define myfunc as int. But when this function is called, it's not assigned to anything, it's just executed like `myfunc(current_id, age);` (not `int i = myfunc(...` for example).

In a situation like this, would it best not to use void? Is it ok to use `return;` in a `void` function?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you declare a prototype somewhere?

Comment: You should show a few lines around line 233 of students.c, sounds like there may be something wrong with the call if it thinks it's a declaration.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, C89 allows functions to be called without prototypes - the compiler will just assume that the function returns `int`.

Comment: Somewhere before you define that function, you have a function prototype. That needs to be changed as well. More than likely it's in a header file named `students.h`

Comment: This was my problem, I had not declared a prototype

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `myfunc()` is declared with no return type (somewhere):

```
myfunc(int id, int age);
```

or there is no declaration at all, so it defaults to an `int` return type. When you specify `void` at the definition:

```
void myfunc(int id, int age)
{
}
```

it does not match the declaration. Change, or add, the declaration:

```
void myfunc(int id, int age);
```

You don't need to explicitly write `return;` in a function with a `void` return type, but you can if you wish.

Comment: Thank you, the declaration there got rid of the warning, I think that the compiler must have thought that the first time I called this function was actually a declaration, that was why it referenced line 233 when it complained that it was already defined as an int

Answer (score 1):

You did the right thing by adding `void` to that implementation of `myfunc`.  However, it looks like the original programmer was sloppy and didn't declare a function prototype for `myfunc` before using it in `students.c`.  Add that prototype somewhere before line 233 and you should be good to go!

Comment: Ah thank you! I was missing a prototype, this got rid of the warning, cheers